# Customized Paging With Repeater And SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, performance, optimization

I've been looking for a good tutorial to teach me how to make a customized Paging control with a simple DataBound control like Repeater to implement a high performance paging feature.

I've found a lot of articles about that issue, but non of them was a complete answer.

- [Paging of Large Resultsets in
  ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=6936&av=45540)

  This one is awesome, with statistics    and great comparison between the    different methods of doing so, but    the problem is it's too old before    SQL Server had it's new function    ROW_NUMBER()
- [N-Layered Web Applications with
  ASP.NET 3.5 Part 4: Sorting, Paging
  and Filtering *(The Database Paging
  Section and ignore the rest)*](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/479/n-layered-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-part-4-sorting-paging-and-filtering)

  This one is almost perfect, but he used the grid's existing paging feature with a customized Method for paging, instead of a repeater.
- [Custom SEO friendly paging with
  ASP.NET Repeater or DataList
  control](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article456-custom-seo-friendly-paging-with-aspnet-repeater-or-datalist-control-.aspx)

  I think this one is WAY too complicated, and things can get done easier

I'm using SQL, Items Repeater (with direct binding in the code-behind with no datasources used), PageNumbers repeater (which will have a link as an ItemTemplate to pass querystring so the used method could retrieve the next portion of Items), A Label to hold the current page number and title.

I've been trying to implement the example on [N-Layered Web Applications with ASP.NET 3.5 Part 4: Sorting, Paging and Filtering *(The Database Paging Section and ignore the rest)*](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/479/n-layered-web-applications-with-aspnet-35-part-4-sorting-paging-and-filtering). So far I've created a SQL command in my Data Access Lyaer that looks like this :

```
WITH Records AS ( SELECT ItemId, ItemName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ItemId) AS 'RowNumber' FROM   Items)  SELECT * FROM Records WHERE (RowNumber BETWEEN (@startIndex) AND @startIndex + @pageSize - 1)
```

but now I'm stuck on how to use it in my presentation layer!

Comment: Looking at your last sample, what issues are you facing implementing it? It needs a method with the id,startindex and pagesize.

Comment: Paging in a repeater is something I've had to teach people in the last 4 job's I've had, there's no good articles on using repeaters, think I'm gonna make it my next blog post.

Comment: @gbs- the repeater which will let me navigate through the pages is my problem. and to be exact I don't know what value should be assigned to the startIndex parameter and how!

Comment: Phill - That would be great! I hope it would be sometime soon and please share it with us when you're done.

Comment: @lKashef - I can't do it till start of feb, got a deadline on a project for feb 1st. Will post a comment here with the link when I've done it.

Comment: @Phill- fair enough =) good luck and waiting for your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom method to render your own pagination control. Here is an example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Produces html for a pagination control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">Page number for the current page (1-based index).</param>
    /// <param name="pageSize">Number or items per page.</param>
    /// <param name="totalItems">Total number of items across all pages.</param>
    /// <returns>Html of a pagination control.</returns>
    public string RenderPaginationControl(int page, int pageSize, int totalItems)
    {
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalItems/pageSize);

        // Create pager.
        StringBuilder pagerSb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; ++i)
        {
            // If it is NOT a link to current page.
            if (i != page) { pagerSb.Append(string.Format("<a href='/data.aspx?page={0}'>{0}</a>", i)); }
            // If it is the link to current page.
            else { pagerSb.Append(string.Format("<span>{0}</span>", i)); }
        }

        return pagerSb.ToString();
    }
```

As you can see apart from your sql, you will also need to call

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Items
```

and pass that value to *totalItems* in the *RenderPaginationControl*.

And as far as the binding to Repeater is concerned - it's pretty straight forward:

```
this.MyRepeater.DataSource = DAL.GetItems(page, pageSize);
this.MyRepeater.DataBind();

int totalItems = DAL.GetTotalNumberOfItems();
this.PaginationLabel.Text = RenderPaginationControl(page, pageSize, totalItems);
```

Comment: @niaher- there's a small bug in the code in the GetItems method. It's not taking a parameter to save the startPageIndex...I don't know how to make it clear to you, but what's missing is a variable that will be the new offset (@startIndex) for my sql query to select a new portion of items for another given page

Comment: @niaher- I solved it by add a "start" QueryString argument to the url and added a variable "startIndex" to the method and incremented it by the pageSize (startIndex += pageSize)...but I wonder if the (StringBuilder+Label) as a paging navigator are better than a repeater.   and last question! I want to use Ajax and Anchors won't let me do it, so I need to use a Server Control instead like a LinkButton to cause a postBack and let my Ajax works! any ideas ?...Marked as answer btw, Thank you =D

Comment: I don't really see why you need the "startIndex" parameter inside the GetItems method. You already know which page you will need for any future requests from the "page" parameter inside each link e.g. - data.aspx?page=2.

Comment: As for using AJAX - I am not sure, but you can try to have a <asp:PlaceHolder> and add controls to it, e.g. - MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(new LinkButton(???)).

Comment: @niaher- "WHERE (RowNumber BETWEEN (@startIndex) AND @startIndex + @pageSize - 1)" the query need to know where a given page will start from. for example if the page size is 4, then page one start will be 1 and page 2 start will be 5 and page 3 start will be 9, etc

Comment: You have to calculate startIndex inside the DAL.GetItems method (or even better if you do that inside your stored procedure). Formula is startIndex = page * pageSize + 1.