# How to read QueryString parameters from a url that's going to be Re-written and hide those parameters in the new re-written URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, url-rewriting

I have two examples to show you what I want to achieve here.
But to point what's different about my question, Is that I'm having a parametrized URLs and I want to implement URL rewriting to my application. But I don't want to convert the parameter in the URL to be placed between slashes..."page.aspx?number=one" to "pages/one/" << NOT!

**First example:**

> http://localhost:1820/Pages/Default.aspx?page=2&start=5

To

> http://localhost:1820/Pages/page2

**Second example:**

> http://localhost:1820/Items/Details.aspx?item=3

To

> http://localhost:1820/Items/ItemName

*But I'll still need all the parameters in the original URLs*

Comment: Two questions: (1) How are you doing URL rewriting? (2) If someone visits localhost/Items/ItemName directly do you still want to be able to say, "What is the value of 'item'" and get back the answer, "3"?

Comment: @Scott Mitchell- (1) I'm not using one yet. and I hope to see a good approach to do what I need. (2) the "item=3" part is the id for this item in the database, and I use this number to retrieve the item which is equal to '3' from my database. but for SEO and cleanliness sake I want to hide the item index and replace it with it's name (which is also a field in the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, you need to somehow store the association between the un-rewritten querystring parameter values with the rewritten URL parameter values.

For example, if you are rewriting:

> http://localhost:1820/Items/Details.aspx?item=3

To:

> http://localhost:1820/Items/Widgets

You must somewhere store that item 3 and Widgets are synonymous. Chances are, you are already doing this. I imagine in your database you have a `Products` table (or whatever) with `ProductID` and `ProductName` columns, and there is a record with `ProductID=3` and `ProductName=Widgets`.

I'd suggest using ASP.NET Routing to handle the URL rewriting. In short, you'd define a routing rule like `Items/{ProductName}` and you would map it to the ASP.NET page `~/Items/Details.aspx`. Such a routing rule says, "Whenever a URL comes in in the form Items/*whatever*, execute the `~/Items/Details.aspx` page." From the `~/Items/Details.aspx` page you can determine the *ProductName* value in the URL programmatically (that is, you can determine that the user is visiting Items/Widgets, in this example) and from that you can load/display the appropriate information.

Check out this article of mine - [URL Routing in ASP.NET 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx). It shows how to use URL rewriting much like you're requesting by using ASP.NET Routing (a built-in library in ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 and up). There's also a working sample application you can download that demonstrates the techniques covered in the article.

Happy Programming!

Comment: @Scott Mitchell- I didn't start using your answer but so far this makes much sense!  A little question, is this approach good for my application scalability and performance or it's just a trick to get it done!

Comment: @IKashef: It'll be good for your application. If the `Products` table was very big you'd want to make sure there was an index on the `ProductName` column (or whatever column value is appearing in the rewritten URL). Also, it might be ideal to actually have a `ProductNameUrl` column that you use in actuality, in case a product had a name with characters that were illegal in a URL.

Comment: @Scott Mitchell- the products for now are like 200 but It will scale over the next two years to be like 2-3 thousands. but from the beginning the load on the website will be huge because it will have many visitors. if a primary key with auto-incremented int field would  apply for what you described as an index on the ProductName then Yes. and thanks for the ProductNameUrl advice +1

Comment: @Scott Mitchell- what if I send the information (name) about the given id (3). Say "id=3&name=shampoo" so I can use the parameters I need (the name) and hide/ignore what I don't need (the id) and at the same time I saved an extra access to the database and the extra code and memory to store those values and manipulate them.

Comment: @IKashef: You can't "hide" the information. If a URL comes in with the querystring parameters you are sending a request BACK to the browser to say, "No, go here instead," and so a NEW request comes in for the NEW URL. There's no way to remember the querystring values. Moreover, users may come in with the "ideal" URL right off the bat (e.g., /Items/Widgets) and so you need to be able to go from Widgets to the ID, 3.

Comment: @Scott Mitchell- well, this is challenging! how about using another way to store my information instead of storing it in the QueryString, maybe some hidden fields or the ViewState. but I wonder if those solutions will have any bad effects ? and will I be able to do URL rewriting in the first place since the url won't change. sorry it's a little bit complicated but I hope to find a reasonable advice.

Comment: @IKashef: The reasonable thing to do is what I shared with you in this answer - namely, when the Details.aspx page is loaded you determine the product name programmatically then do a query on the database for the product with that matching name. It's identical to what you would do with the parameters in the querystring, except here you are looking up by `ProductName` rather than `ProductID`. Please be sure to read the article I cited and download the code - you'll see it isn't that challenging or exotic. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your examples you are removing data from the URL entirely, and I don't see that there is going to be a way of doing what you want here.

For example your first url with the /default.aspx?page=2&start=5 that you want to become /pages/page2.

In theory, default.aspx?page=2 and default.aspx?page=2&start=5 could be different behaviors.  How would you want to represent that.  As  you wouldn't have a way of calling the former if /pages/page2 always mapped to that of the second example.

I guess we would need to know a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578781/customized-paging-with-repeater-and-sql. referring to the question I just posted, you can see page=2 and start=5 are paired forever, this is not going to change unless I change the pageSize